# PdfLoadedDocument filenot found

Tags: c#

I try to load a pdf document using `PdfLoadedDocument` method from `Syncfusion.Pdf.WinForms` NuGet package.

The code is pretty simple and look like this:

```
PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(@"\\server\folder\sample.pdf");
```

But it raises file not found error.

Comment: The file is not here

Comment: I think he means the file probably is there but the file path format could be incorrect. I remember my struggles with defining the correct path format

Comment: This file path is pretty straightforward.

Comment: This file path did not retrieve his file. I assume he checked if the file existed before he asks this question

Comment: The file path format is pretty correct. Sadly, you should not assume what as been tested.

Comment: @Sindra, where did you get the `Syncfusion.Pdf` libraries ?

Comment: @Orace from nuget library

Comment: @sindra, witch package ? I tried the last version of the `Syncfusion.Pdf.Net.Core` NuGet package. And there is no overload of `PdfLoadedDocument` that accept a string as a parameter, your code can't even compile.

Comment: @orace it's Syncfusion.Pdf.WinForms

Comment: @sindra, what exactly is the error message you got ? For an invalid path the exact message is: `System.ArgumentException: 'File doesn't exist
Parameter name: filename'`

Comment: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

You may:

- Test manually if the file is here: open your file explorer and enter the path, does the file open ?
- Test programmatically if the file is here: Put `File.Exists(@"\\server\folder\sample.pdf")` in your code. This may raise other issues (like `access denied` that the `PdfLoadedDocument` may have swallowed).

**Edit**:

If you take a look to de-compiled code of `PdfLoadedDocument` (from `Syncfusion.Pdf.WinForms v17.4.0.46` NuGet package) it is:

```
public PdfLoadedDocument(string filename)
  : this(PdfLoadedDocument.CreateStream(filename))
{
  this.isDispose = true;
  this.m_bCloseStream = true;
  this.m_fileName = filename;
}
```

The `PdfLoadedDocument.CreateStream` code is:

```
if (filename == null)
  throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (filename));
if (!File.Exists(filename))
  throw new ArgumentException("File doesn't exist", nameof (filename));
...
```

So the `"File doesn't exist"` exception occurs when `File.Exists` return false.

If you take a look to `File.Exists` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.8):

> The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file.

The file may be there but your program may not have the right to access it.

Anyway, I tested `PdfLoadedDocument(@"\\server\users\Orace\test.pdf");` where I have full access to `\\server\users\Orace`, and it works fine.

Comment: He would have checked if the file existed before asking this question, to reperform such checks is no answer to the question

Comment: The `Programmatically` part is important. And we can't assume that OP really tested the file to be there.

Comment: Perhaps I am naive to think he checked the existence of the file first

Comment: @MwBakker actually, in the `Syncfusion.Pdf.Net.Core` NuGet package there is no overload of `PdfLoadedDocument` that accept a string as a parameter, the OP code can't compile.

Comment: @Orace there is a filename, see my updated question

Comment: @MwBakker I did the file exist check and it's there. So I guess the url path is not correct for this method?

Comment: here's tthe reference: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9072/how-to-add-watermark-to-pdf-file-in-c-vb-net

Comment: @sindra, Have you try `File.Exists` ? `File.Open` ?

Comment: @orace it's Syncfusion.Pdf.WinForms

Comment: @sindra. Does `File.Exists(@"\\server\folder\sample.pdf")` return true ?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/file-formats/Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing.PdfLoadedField.html

```
using Syncfusion.Pdf;

using Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics;

using Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing; //<================


namespace Text_Extraction
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
            {
            // Load an existing PDF document.

            PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new 
PdfLoadedDocument(@"C:\Users\grayg\Documents\Text To Speech 
Stuff\NationalTreeClimbingGuide2015April.pdf");

            // Loading page collections
```